# Check whether a list is present in sublist containing list, tuples

Tags: python, list, tuples, enumerate

I have a list containing sublists and the sublists contain other lists and tuples something like this

```
[[(1.0, 1.5), [2, 2], (1.5, 1.0)], [(1.1428571343421936, 0.28571426868438721), [1, 0], (0.5, 0.0)], [(0.66666668653488159, 0.0), [0, 0], [0, 1], (0.5, 1.25)]]
```

I want to search whether `[2,2]` exists in a sublist or not and print the index of that sublist containing `[2,2]`. For eg. the sublist containing `[2,2]` is `0`.

I tried using the following code but it gives all the elements in an increasing fashion.

```
for index, value in enumerate(flat_list):
    if value == [xpred,ypred]:
        print(index)
```

Please suggest some alternative !!

Comment: What is `value`?

Comment: I have edited the question !! Please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
l = [[(1.0, 1.5), [2, 2], (1.5, 1.0)], [(1.1428571343421936, 0.28571426868438721), [1, 0], (0.5, 0.0)], [(0.66666668653488159, 0.0), [0, 0], [0, 1], (0.5, 1.25)]] 

is_in_l = [l.index(pos) for pos in l if [2,2] in pos]
if is_in_l:
    print('List Available at {} position'.format(is_in_l[0]))
else:
    print('List not present')
```

Comment: ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Comment: works fine for me with above list.. can you update your implementation ..

Answer (score 1):

Here is some code that might help:

```
x = [[(1.0, 1.5), [2, 2], (1.5, 1.0)],
     [(1.1428571343421936, 0.28571426868438721), [1, 0], (0.5, 0.0)],
     [(0.66666668653488159, 0.0), [0, 0], [0, 1], (0.5, 1.25)]]

looking_for = [2,2]

for i in range(len(x)):
  for j in range(len(x[i])):
    if x[i][j] == looking_for:
        print([i,j])
```

I have made a nested for loop. The outer loop iterates over all the items in the list x. These items are lists itself. The second for loop iterates within the sublists. Lastly, it is checked whether the tuple or list corresponds to what you are looking for and the indices of the ones that do are printed.

Hope this answers your question and good luck with you coding!